# How to access the location of the changelog file from custom task in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I need to access the location of the change log file so that I can get the URL of other files that are in the same directory from a custom task.

The Change interface has a setter for the ChangeSet object which can be used to get the change log file, but the CustomChangeTask interface does not have this method.

From my understanding I need to use CustomChangeTask as my task does not generate SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my question. I have decided to implement AbstractChange. It works just fine doing that and returning an empty array of SqlStatements.